# Delphi How to force Main form scrollbars to be visible

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

What options/properties should use to show a main from scrolbars when I want to?
or always visible in Delphi 2010
The help is as too often useless
thanks
Pw

Answer (score 7):

@Philippe, you can use the [ShowScrollBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787601%28VS.85%29.aspx) function and the HorzScrollBar, VertScrollBar propeties to do this.

check this code

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HorzScrollBar.Range := 10000; // set the range to an higher number
  VertScrollBar.Range := 10000; // set the range to an higher number
  ShowScrollBar(Handle, SB_BOTH, True);
end;
```

Comment: Then please mark this as the answer to your question. And don't forget to also do this with all your other questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you set AutoScroll = true, they should show up if needed. That is, if any visual component is placed outside of the visible client area.

If you do not have any components 'off-screen', why would you need the scrollbar showing?

Anyway, you can set Horz-/VertScrollBar.Range to anything larger than the clientheight/width, and they will show up.

If you need the scrollbar for something else, you can always drop a TScrollBar component on the form.